# Problems parsing out Strings

Tags: string, parsing

Please help...I have a file with the following format of data:
b 100 42.47 MSFT

I want to grab the '100' and convert it to an integer.  I'm doing:

```
num = Integer.parseInt(s.substring((s.indexOf(" ") + 1), (s.indexOf(" "))));
```

which should work but I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you s.Split(" ") and then get at the 2nd element of the returned array ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what language you're using, but either way I don't think your indexes are what you want.  If you're in C#, then the end of what you're extracting will start with the first character after the first space and continue for the number of characters from the beginning of the string to the first space.  If you're in Java, you're extracting from the first character after the first space to the first space, which of course is before the first character after.  That would explain your index error.  You want the second "indexOf" to start at (or relative to) the indexOf the first space and not at the start of the string.